# Accessing buttons on stage from class

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, apache-flex, class, flash-builder

I need some help here..

I need to set properties of buttons on the main stage from the current class. How would I do this?

I have multiple buttons on my stage. Each representing a chapter in a movie (from frame x to frame y of the movie).

When I push one of them, the movie plays. When it gets to the end, it should continue to the next segment/chapter. This works, but now I need to highlight the current button, not let the button I pressed be highlighted forever..

Any ideas?

Working in Flash Builder.

Comment: are these buttons on different frames?

Comment: It's flash builder. No "frames" like in flash. So no. =)

Comment: Yh I'm aware that flash builder doesn't have a timeline but my confusion came from this statement "I have multiple buttons on my stage. Each representing a chapter in a movie (from frame x to frame y of the movie)."

Comment: Ahh, my mistake. What I mean by "chapters" is simply a time frame where the next part begins in the movie. The movie itself is one long clip. So by skipping to the next chapter I just seek to the time I've specified.

I did rewrite the whole code now, since it was a simple app, so now everything is on the main class/project file. But would be interesting to know in the future =)

My problem was that I had to change the toggled state of my buttons (which is in my main mxml file) from an external class I've made.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, fire an custom event from the class, and listen for this event in the main app. In the handler of the event, set the button properties to whatever you need.

Brian

Comment: Thanks, but how do I fire custom events?